# Firestore and VueJS: How to update field in nested object in a firestore collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I have a nested object within a document that I am trying to update. I am trying to update the `avatarUrl` property in the `author` object of my `photos` collection (see screenshot below). **However, despite looking at the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#update_fields_in_nested_objects) and using dot notation, I can't seem to update my field!**

Here's my reference I am trying to update: photos > docId > author.avatarUrl

[image]

Here is my relevant code. When I let user update his avatar URL, I also need to update all his docs with his new avatar

> When I let user update his avatar URL, I also need to update all his docs with his new avatar

```
        // update all photo docs by user
        const photoDocs = await this.$fireStore
          .collection('photos')
          .where('userId', '==', this.userProfile.uid)
          .get()
        photoDocs.forEach((doc) => {
          this.$fireStore.collection('photos').doc(doc.id).update({
            'author.avatarUrl': this.avatarUrl
          })
        })
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be checking for errors anywhere.  Something could go wrong and you'd never know.